# Issue using google map apiV2 full screen in SherlockFragmentActivity with actionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having issue trying to use GoogleMapApi V2 with the same code that i use in other applications. **All i want is to do StartActivity(MapActivityFragment); without errors**

**I have those permissions**

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.egdigital.appetablissement.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.egdigital.appetablissemen" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="theApiKey" />

<activity
    android:name="com.egdigital.appetablissement.ActivityGoogleMap"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

**The XML that contains the map support fragment : activity_maps**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**And this class to manage the map**

```
public class ActivityGoogleMap extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    }
}
```

I have included ActionBarSherlock and googlePlayServices-lib **as libraries**

also included android-support-v4.jar **as external jar and added it to dependencies**

When i do StartActivity(MapActivityFragment) i get this big dirty error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.egdigital.appetablissement/com.egdigital.appetablissement.ActivityGoogleMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.egdigital.appetablissement-1.apk
```

Comment: What is `egdigital.appetablissement.ihm.TransparentSupportMapFragment`?

Comment: it's a class that extends supportMapFragment. i used it for testing since i didn't get any positive results. i have the same trace with com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: trace updated with the good log

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some bad formatting surrounding the `<application>` and `<meta-data>` elements in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So, the following:

```
<application
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="theApiKey" />

<activity
    android:name="com.egdigital.appetablissement.ActivityGoogleMap"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

...should be changed to:

```
<application>        
    <activity
        android:name="com.egdigital.appetablissement.ActivityGoogleMap"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="theApiKey">
</application>
```

The Android Maps API v2 docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application

...say:

> In AndroidManifest.xml, add the [meta-data] element as a child of the  element, by inserting it just before the closing tag `</application>`.